# How to limit an array and split it into more arrays? PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, split

I would like to do this...

I got this array with 50 elements

```
$data = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50);
```

and I would like to add the first 20 elements into another array, 20 should be the limit, if it is greater than 20 add the next 20 into another array and do this operation to only get array with 20 elements

I tried with this

```
$number = count($data);    
$pieces = array_chunk($data, ceil($number / 2));
```

And I get only two sub-arrays from that, I'm lost, I need some ideas about how to achieve this, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you're only trying to get 2 subarrays, since you're taking the total number and dividing it by 2. You're on the right track, you just need to specify the number of elements you want in each subarray:

```
$pieces = array_chunk($data, 20);
```

Comment: Thank you, `array_chunk` works like `array_slice`?, your answer solved my problem :) I was confused, thank you so much.

Comment: Sort of. Think of taking a piece of wood and chopping it up. `array_chunk` starts at the beginning, cuts up the pieces into the requested size, puts it all in a box and hands it back to you. `array_slice` takes that wood, cuts out the requested piece and hands just that part back to you.